# Bash does not detect that file exists

Tags: bash

I have made a bash alias to execute scripts before and after the `cd` command. The only issue is it does not execute the files.

Here is my code

```
cd(){
if [ -d "./.dinit" ]
then
    echo "dinit file exists"
    source ./.dinit
fi
builtin cd $@
if [ -d "./.init"  ]
then
    echo "init file exists"
    source ./.init
fi
}
```

In the *.init* file I have the command `echo hello` and in the *.dinit* I have `echo goodbye`

When I get this working I am going to put `PATH=` statements in the files along with alias.

Does anyone know how I can get the commands to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checks right now look for directories, which you then try to source. That doesn't really make any sense, so I'm assuming that those are really the *files* you want to source. In which case, you should use `-f` to check for a regular file instead:

```
cd(){
if [ -f "./.dinit" ]
then
    echo "dinit file exists"
    source ./.dinit
fi
builtin cd "$@"
if [ -f "./.init"  ]
then
    echo "init file exists"
    source ./.init
fi
}
```